# List of lists to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this list of lists:

```
dictlist= [['AUGUSTIN', 56725, 'Mar 2016', 0, 600], ['AUGUSTIN', 56725, 'Feb 2015', 600, 600], ['BOT', 52634, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 291, 291]]
```

And I want to have a function to group them after index 1, and my desired output should be like this:

```
{56725: ['AUGUSTIN', 'Feb 2015', 600, 600], 52634: ['BOT', 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 291, 291]}
```

But I try with this function:

```
def to_dict(lst): return {x[0]: x[1:] for x in lst}
```

But my output is this:

```
{'AUGUSTIN': [56725, 'Feb 2015', 600, 600], 'BOT': [52634, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 291, 291]}
```

How I can fix it so I will get my desired output? I use python 3.

Comment: `x[1]: x[:1] + x[2:] for ...`?

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: Why is `Feb 2015` preferred over `Mar 2016`?

Answer (score 3):

use dict comprehension, `pop(1)` extract index 1 item as the key and the rest as the value of the dictionary item

```
def to_dict(lst): 
    return {x[:].pop(1): x for x in lst}
```

this will return your desire output dictionary, however the order will not follow the input list since normal dictionary will not be in order,
also, there is 2 list item with index 1 56725, the later item will overwrite the previous same key, so output will only keep the later

Comment: this mutates the original data

Comment: @Jared Goguen, thanks for pointing that out, already edited the answer to copy the inner list first to avoid mutaating original data

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any issue with this:

```
dictlist= [['AUGUSTIN', 56725, 'Mar 2016', 0, 600], ['AUGUSTIN', 56725, 'Feb 2015', 600, 600], ['BOT', 52634, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 291, 291]]
def to_dict(lst): 
    return {x.pop(1):x for x in lst}

to_dict(dictlist)
```

Comment: But it modifies the list so could use x.copy()

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over your list and create a dictionary.

```
dictlist= [['AUGUSTIN', 56725, 'Mar 2016', 0, 600], ['AUGUSTIN', 56725, 'Feb 2015', 600, 600], ['BOT', 52634, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 291, 291]]

dicta = {x[1]: x[:1] + x[2:]  for x in [y for y in dictlist]}

# {56725: ['AUGUSTIN', 'Feb 2015', 600, 600], 52634: ['BOT', 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 291, 291]}
```

Comment: Oh this one *is* a list comp, sorry. But it creates a list of dictionaries, which isn’t what the OP wants.

Comment: @akashkarothiya I think it is called dictionary creation using list comprehension.

Comment: absolutely, I agree with you @bhansa

Comment: Except now the description is wrong and both lines you suggest include two loops for absolutely no reason.